# React Native Background Task To Get Updates From Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app, background-task

My problem is that I want to add a background service in the mobile app that will hit firebase every 5 to 10 minutes when the mobile app is in background mode and get the updated data and when any important info is been get from firebase it will ring a ringtone in my mobile phone and when I touch on it, it will open up the app with updated info.

Comment: I think you can use Headless JS. Take a look into this -> https://reactnative.dev/docs/headless-js-android

Comment: Thank You Ill try it